# If statement in Lua

Tags: lua

i'm trying to do simplest of things:

- program prints first message and waits for user input
- user types in "play" or "leave"
- if user types in "play" program prints "let's play" and exits (for now)
- if user types in "leave" program prints "bye" and exits
- if user types in something different than "play" or "leave" program
  prints first message and waits for user input again

however current code just prints first message 2 times and exits:

```
print("welcome. you have 2 options: play or leave. choose.")
input = io.read()

if input == "play" then
print("let's play")
end

if input == "leave" then
print("bye")
end

if input ~= "play" or "leave" then
print("welcome. you have 2 options: play or leave. choose.")
end
```

what is wrong here? any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: what is `input`?

Comment: i've edited code: input = io.read(). problem is that after any user input program prints first message one more time and exits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `if` statement will only execute once. It doesn't jump to other parts of the program. To do that you need to wrap your input code in a `while` loop and break out when you get a valid response:

```
while true do
  print("welcome. you have 2 options: play or leave. choose.")
  local input = io.read()

  if input == "play" then
    print("let's play")
    break
  elseif input == "leave" then
    print("bye")
    break
  end

end
```

Read more about loops [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.2.html).

Answer (score 1):

The line `if input ~= "play" or "leave" then` is evaluated as:

```
if (input ~= "play") or "leave" then
```

The string `"leave"`, or any string for that matter, is considered a truthy value.

You need to compare both strings, using `and`:

```
if input ~= "play" and input ~= "leave" then
    print("welcome. you have 2 options: play or leave. choose.")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop, as you can see this while here is saying, if the input isn't exit, redo the code, and the else means that it will check for the if, the elseif, then finally, the else.

```
print("welcome. you have 2 options: play or leave. choose.")

while input ~= "exit" do
     input = io.read()
     if input == "play" then
         print("let's play")
     elseif input == "leave" then
         print("bye")
     else
         print("welcome. you have 2 options: play or leave. choose.")
     end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual idiom is

```
if input == "play" then
   print("let's play")
elseif input == "leave" then
   print("bye")
else
   print("welcome. you have 2 options: play or leave. choose.")
end
```

but you probably need a loop as suggested by @luther.